# Symfony mailer: Swift_TransportException between message sending

Tags: symfony1, swiftmailer

On a current project which I'm currently working, i have a symfony task that runs some mass data insertion to database and runs it for at least half an hour.
When the task starts a mail notification is sent correctly, the problem is that at the of the task execution we can't send another mail to notify about the end of processing.

The mailer factory is currently configured with the spool delivery strategy but, in this specific situation, we desire to fire a notification immediately, using the sendNextImmediately() method.

I'm are getting the exception:

> [Swift_TransportException]
>     Expected response code 250 but got code "451", with message "451 4.4.2 Timeout - closing connection. 74sm1186065wem.17
>     "

and the flowing error on php log file:

> Warning: fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe in /var/www/project/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 209

Can anyone give some help?
Is there any way that i can perhaps refresh symfony mailer to establish a new connection?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using the send the second message. You're creating a new instance of swiftmailer, right?

Comment: @Tom The Code for each message is quite similar: $message = $this->getMailer()->compose(); $message->setFrom(sfConfig::get('app_notifications_from_address'), sfConfig::get('app_notifications_from_address_name')); $message->setTo(sfConfig::get('app_notifications_to_error_support_address')); $message->setBody($html, 'text/html'); $this->getMailer()->sendNextImmediately()->send($message); Am i missing something?

Comment: ok good, looks like you resolved it. That's more or less what I was after... either stop/start or a new instance altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Symfony1 Users

My guess was that the connection was being hold for too long (with no activity at all), causing an ssl connection timeout.

For now, the problem can be solved by stopping the `Swift_Transport` instance and starting it again explicitly, just before sending the second message.

**Here is the code:**

```
$this->getMailer()->getRealtimeTransport()->stop();
$this->getMailer()->getRealtimeTransport()->start();
$this->getMailer()->sendNextImmediately()->send($message);
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing a Symfony2 project, I ran across this failure too. We were using a permanently running php script, which produced the error.

We figured out that following code does the job:

```
private function sendEmailMessage($renderedTemplate, $subject, $toEmail)
    {
        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
        /* @var $mailer \Swift_Mailer */
        if(!$mailer->getTransport()->isStarted()){
            $mailer->getTransport()->start();
        }
        $sendException = null;
        /* @var $message \Swift_Message */
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($this->getContainer()->getParameter('email_from'))
            ->setTo($toEmail)
            ->setBody($renderedTemplate);


        $mailer->send($message);
        $mailer->getTransport()->stop();
        //throw $sendException;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome reply @stoefln. However, this has a major impact on performance. If the connection is held, I can send `1 email/2.4s` whereas if we close the connection each time using your script, I can send `1 email/5.1s`. Maybe a great idea would be to set a timer. Do you have any idea how long it takes for a connection to timeout, for example with gmail?

Comment: @Patt you are right. unfortunately I have no idea how to set the timer :/ we switched to opening the connection sending a bunch of emails and closing it after that.

Comment: That's a good idea @stoefln. If we knew how long it would take before a connection drops out the idea of a timer would be doable, but it looks like it depends on the provider. If I find anything good, I'll put a gist (your answer saved me some time so many thanks) :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and above solutions were very helpful, but there is one thing I had to do differently: order.

```
$this->getMailer()->sendNextImmediately()->send($message);
$this->getMailer()->getRealtimeTransport()->stop();
```

It didn't worked for me if I tried to stop Transport before sending message (connection timeout was already hanging). Also You don't need to run getRealtimeTransport()->start() - it will be started automatically.